# Dynamic IP Restriction

Tags: ip

We have configured Dynamic IP Restriction in IIS 8.  What I want to know is does Dynamic IP Restriction in IIS 8 block HTTP only or can it also block TCP and UDP request that violate the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find a good solution here:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/block-open-port-windows-8-firewall

or If your server is behind a router (like Cisco-asa) than Write rules there.